# C# referencing a Grid in WPF to change properties

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello im new to making apps with WPF and XAML in Visual Studio. So I have a grid I want to change its properties in the code.

My Grid's properties:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="603"
              Margin="0,51,0,0"
              x:Name="usersPan"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="1286">
```

How I have been trying to change its properties

```
        this.usersPan.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, PAN_SIZE);
        usersPan.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, PAN_SIZE);
        usersPan.Width = 0;
        usersPan.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

When I try to do that^ it says null reference for userPan

Thanks

Comment: what type of your `PAN_SIZE`?

Comment: Do you call the code before the call to `InitializeComponent();` method?

Answer (score 2):

Noooooooo, Don't ever do that. Make a ViewModel that is bound to the Grid's Width property, and then just change the value.

My suspicion is that you do not need this at all. Have a look into containers, and how to position them.

In all of this years, there have been rare occasions I needed to do that and I suspect you do not need to. Tell me what you are doing.

**EDIT:**
    You have a VM which needs to implement the NotifyPropertyChanged interface (I won't do that here, there are plenty of examples on hoew to do that)

```
public class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabVM> TabsVms {get;set;}
    public int SelectedIndex {get;set}
}
```

bound to the control

```
<TabControl DataContext={TabsVMs} SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    ...
</TabControl>
```

And in runtime you create a couple of Tabs

```
var TabsVMs = new ObservableCollection<TabVM>();
TabsVMs.add(new TabVM());
TabsVMs.add(new TabVM());
TabsVMs.add(new TabVM());
```

Then in runtime you change the value of the index.

```
MainVm.SelectedIndex = 1
```

and the the coresponding tab will become selected.

**EDIT:**
I can also recommend you to use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) for the MVVM notification.
Also, when it comes to bindings, I can recommend you to use WPF inspector. a handy little tool

Comment: The goal is it have a Grid disappear so I can make other grids visible. So I can do something like a Tab Control like in forms

Comment: You have a tab control built into WPF. You create a list of TabViewModels and bind it to the TabControl. Then in the Viewmodel you say which ViewModel object is selected, and WPF will react by selecting the tab you want.

Comment: WPF and MVVM is reactional. You change the data and it will react to the data. in XAML you only say in which way it it react.

Comment: I should of done some research lol. I was able to get radio buttons to kinda do the same and it doesn't look too bad

Comment: It does not matter if you did it or not. If you did, .... change it.
First read a bit about WPF and its design pattern called MVVM. might seem like an overhead, but trust me, you will be glad you did

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly why Grid is invisible in code-behind, but You can access it's properties using events (but don't think it is perfect solution).

For example add to your grid event `Loaded`

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="603"
              Margin="0,51,0,0"
              x:Name="usersPan"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="1286"
              Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
```

and then from code-behind you can access grid in next way:

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.Width = 0;
        }
    }
```

---

Better solution :

Add some boolean property to your ViewModel like `public bool IsGridVisible{get;set;}`

And bind it to your Grid

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Height="603"
                  Margin="0,51,0,0"
                  x:Name="usersPan"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="1286" 
                  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsGridVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}">
```

where BoolToVis is converter which converts true to Visible and false to Hidden. You can define it in App.xaml like :

```
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, im going the right direction now

Comment: Why do people keep posting answers like this and pushing the guy into the abyss, where he needs to realise he went down the wrong stream and needs to learn about  WPF and MVVM

Comment: @user853710, as I've written in my answer it isn't perfect solution.

Comment: isn't perfect? It's the worst possible !!! Don't give the guy a fish, teach him to fish. I'm a bit emotional about that because I had to maintain a project that the guy started to like that, and afterwards quit his job.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to write WPF programs is to use the MVVM (Model-View-View Model) design pattern. There are two (2) ideas behind MVVM:

1. Write as little code as possible in the view's code-behind and put all of the logic in the View Model object, using WPF's data binding feature to connect the properties of the View Model object to the view's controls.
2. Separate the logic from the display so you can replace the view with some other construct without having to change the logic.

MVVM is a huge topic on its own.  There are lots of articles about it, and frameworks that you can use to build your program.  Check out MVVM Light, for example.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do something like this so I can change properties outside of an event.

```
    private Grid userGrid;
    private void onUserGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        userGrid = sender as Grid;
    }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary.  You gave the `Grid` control a name; you should be able to change its properties by using the name in the code behind, after `InitializeComponent()` is called.  Further, make sure you spell the name consistently everywhere.  Case counts!